# A question about prime numbers, totient function $ \phi(n) $ and sum of divisors function $ \sigma(n) $

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum

I noticed something interesting with  the totient function $ \phi(n) $ and sum of divisors function $ \sigma(n) $ when $n > 1$.

It seems than :

$ \sigma(4n^2-1) \equiv 0  \pmod{\phi(2n^2)}$ only if $ 2n - 1 $ is a prime number.

for example :

$ \sigma(4 \cdot 6^2-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(2 \cdot 6^2)} $ and $ 2 \cdot 6 - 1 = 11$ and $11$ is a prime number.

$ \sigma(4 \cdot 7^2-1) \equiv 0 \pmod{\phi(2 \cdot 7^2)} $ and $ 2 \cdot 7 - 1 = 13$ and $13$ is a prime number.

I found this sequences of primes : $``3,5,11,13,19,29,31,53,67,83,103,113,131,139,193,233,251,271,313,383,389 ..."$

I've checked until $n = 1000000$ and I didn't find any counterexamples.

This sequence is not on OEIS.

I would like to know why some primes are here and some primes are not here. This is only an coincidence or not ? And if not, is there a way to prove it ?

Comment: Maybe $\sigma(4n^2-1)=\sigma(2n-1)\sigma(2n+1)$ helps.

Comment: well $n|\phi(2n^2)$

Comment: Conjecture holds upto $n=10^9$

Comment: Let us consider $x=2n$. As @Lucid has stated, it is easy to show that $x\mid\phi\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$, so by transitivity $\phi\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \mid \sigma(x-1)\sigma(x+1)$ only if $x \mid \sigma(x-1)\sigma(x+1)$. As $\sigma(x-1)=x$ if $x-1$ is prime, it would suffice to show that $x \nmid \sigma(x-1)\sigma(x+1)$ unless $\sigma(x-1)=x$

Answer (score 1):

This question is certainly difficult to solve.

Let $x=2n$. As @Lucid has stated in the comments, it is easy to show that $x\mid\phi\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$, so by transitivity $\phi\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right) \mid \sigma(x-1)\sigma(x+1)$. As $\sigma(x-1)=x$ if $x-1$ is prime, to validate the OP conjecture it would suffice to show that $x \nmid \sigma(x-1)\sigma(x+1)$ unless $\sigma(x-1)=x$. But this task seems quite difficult.

Comment: It's even harder than that, because $x\mid ab$ does not force $x\mid a$ or $x\mid b$.

Comment: @GregMartin true! I was supposing that $\gcd(\sigma(x-1),\sigma(x+1))=1$, but that could be not the case. Edited appropriately.

Comment: Indeed, since $\sigma(k)$ is even unless $k$ is a perfect square or twice a perfect square, $\gcd(\sigma(x-1),\sigma(x+1))$ will almost never equal $1$.